# NodeJS UDP limit

Tags: node.js, networking, udp

Is there a max to how many UDP packets NodeJS can received and send every second. I was working on a game where there is a connection manager that sends heart beats. But it ended up not working because once I started sending packets with the world state so many times a second,  it slowed down everything on the socket (both receiving and sending).

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: No particular hard coded limit.  It will depend upon your OS, your CPU and how much processing you're doing for each UDP packet.  It will help you diagnose if you figure out where your bottleneck is by looking at nodejs CPU usage, OS network pipe usage, etc...  It sounds like you are either saturating one CPU or you've saturated the bandwidth in/out of your server.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok, I think I might just put this project of to the side for now. If the start of my project is already taking up too much CPU usage I can't anticipate it going much better if I go further.

Comment: Are you just guessing that it's CPU usage causing the issue?  Or did you actually see a CPU utilization for one core pegged at 100%?  Also, how many UDP packets are you trying to send per second?  If you were trying to send 500 packets/second and each packet took 2ms of CPU to process, you'd saturate a single CPU, just doing that. FYI, there's also the nodejs cluster module for involving more CPUs in your processing (escaping the single threaded/single CPU nature of nodejs).

Comment: Hmm you make a good point it seems like it is not the cpu usage. The weird things is it seems like things are being done in bursts. Like it is receiving the messages from the client in bursts when I am also sending packets to the client. I'm using Godot and gd-com as my client and its started to seem like that's where the problem is. When I used a nodejs client I didn't get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Look at this issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39092 and the linked PR
(Disclaimer: I am the author of the issue and the PR)

All I/O in Node.js passes through the event loop and there is usually a maximum amount of work that can be done in one iteration - determined by the buffer size. The event loop is executed every time your JavaScript program relinquishes control of the CPU - by calling an async function and either directly `await`ing or waiting for a `.then` to be called.

If your program does uninterruptible synchronous calculations that take 0.5s every time it is called, then the event loop won't run more than twice per second. If the internal buffer cannot hold all the packets that will accumulate during these 0.5s, they won't be processed.

In this case, the maximum number of UDP packets that can be processed will be *max_udp_queue_length* multiplied per 2.